# problem with manage.py: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django

When I tried to execute python manage.py runserver, it failed due to the SyntaxError. Then I tried it with python 3, it still didn't help and said "No module named 'django'".
[image]

However, when I searched the packages in my virtualenv, it seemed that django is inside this virtualenv.
[image]

It seems like it's using the local packages but not the packages inside the virtualenv.

Can someone help me resolve this problem? Thx

Comment: your `virtual environment` probably uses `python3`. Trying using it to run the django server.

Comment: @Abhyudai I have tried python3 and you can see the result from pic 1. It said No module named 'django'.

Comment: @Anthelion, no you haven't used python3.
Try writing the same command as: `python3 manage.py runserver`

Comment: @Anthelion What's the output of the command `python --version`?